# apt-key won't trust the gpg certificate

Tags: debian, apt

I am trying to setup my own `Debian` repo, don't ask why :P, following the steps from [here](https://earthly.dev/blog/creating-and-hosting-your-own-deb-packages-and-apt-repo/)

While everything seems OK, the `apt update` won't accept my repo

```
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9C7C30D8EBE3A31C
```

Note: I am trying `apt update` from another machine, not the one I hosted my repo on

I thought importing public gpg cert on the remote machine should work so I tried this:

```
- gpg import <public_key>
- Also added it to trust [ultimate]
- Verified that the gpg --verify against the InRelease file and the import certificate reports good
```

But it seems that `apt-key` may be using it's own trust store so being inspired by the `apt-key` [manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt-key.8.html), I did this

```
cat pgp-key.public | apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/myrepo.gpg add -
OK
```

But no luck :( `apt-key` keeps throwing that error. I can see that `9C7C30D8EBE3A31C` matches the last 4 blocks from the trusted key output

```
apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/myrepo.gpg
---------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2022-08-14 [SCEA]
      F0E2 600D C4A4 408B AA69  59B8 9C7C 30D8 EBE3 A31C
uid           [ unknown] example <example@example.com>
```

Any luck on what to do.

**Note: I think I can still upgrade with `--allow-unauthenticated` option an update with `--allow-insecure-repositories` option but I wish to get rid of this error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue :)

Since `apt-key` is maintaining its own set of trusted key, this is how I modified the steps:

- Don't specify `[signed-by=<file-path>]` in the source list

And import the public key to `apt-key` trusted sources

```
cat pgp-key.public | apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/myrepo.gpg add -
```

With this simple change, `apt` no longer complains about public key and will happily upgrade